# Script to load Wi-Fi profiles

Tags: wireless-networking, xml, profile

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and I need a script to load 2 wifi profiles. I have exportred the XMLs from a current system.  I just need a way to deploy the profiles to people who don't know the first thing about Windows.

I would prefer that I could embed the profiles inside the script if possible.  These are networks that are not broadcasting their SSIDs.

Comment: Sounds like your trying to make your own war driving software 'o.o

Comment: If so I want beta access.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is a batch script that does `netsh wlan add profile filename=foobar.xml` for each profile. Make sure you save the passwords in the clear though as per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/133097/netsh-wlan-add-profile-not-importing-encrypted-passphrase) question. It's going to be a lot easier to simply keep the XML files with the script rather than trying to combine them in a single file.